# Unable to fetch & Write more than 1000 rows from Jira through Python RestApi

Tags: python, csv, jira, jira-rest-api

Through Python Rest Api , i am trying to write a loop which fetched less than 1000/ more than 1000 or even 10000 rows from Jira.
Normally and with the below code, only less than 1000 rows are being captured.
Could anyone help in how to get more than 1000 rows through Rest Api from Jira.

```
from jira import JIRA
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

#creating jira session and establish a connection
jira_session=requests.session()
try:
   jira_session.post('https://onjira.xxx.com',auth=("username","password"),verify=False)
   print("Able to connect to jira")

except:
   print("Unable to connect to jira")


url='https://onjira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=((project=YYYY and createdDate>=startofMonth()))'

query_params={
           "startAt":0,
           "maxResults":1000}

results=[]
df2=pd.DataFrame()

while True:
         response=jira_session.get(url,params=query_params)
         data1=response.json()
         project_data=data1['issues']
         df=pd.DataFrame(data=project_Data)
         df1=df['fields'].apply(pd.Series)
         
        df2['Key']=df1['votes'].apply(lambda a:a['self'].split('/')[-2] if a is not None else '')
        df2['Summary]=df1['summary]

        # if StartAt+MaxResults is less greater than total then break
        if query_params['startAt]+query_params['maxResults'] >=data1['total']
                break
       
        else:
           query_params['startAt'] +=query_params['maxResults']

df2.to_csv('Final_data.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Since jira supports pagination, you need to call the APIs iteratively, the way you are calling in your python code! I am unclear on what your question is..... or What kind of issue you are facing. If your question is that you are unable to fetch more than `1000` results in SINGLE API call then it is expected behaviour of API in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for the response. My expectation is to see if there is way to read more than 1000 rows from jira & write the same in a csv

Comment: It doesn't matter what your expectation is. JIra Server / Datacenter will only return a maximum of 1,000 objects in a single request. Thereafter, you have to use pagination, exactly as @Kartoos said.